# Bitbucket pipelines- different branches on different instances

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a flow for my app that I have one instance named as Staging and the other is QA and then there is a Production instance. We create branches from Staging and once verifies, they are then merged into staging, then to QA and then into master once verified completely.
I am new to the pipelines and I want to achieve the below flow

- If some branch is pushed, deployment should take place only on Staging EC2 instance and that branch should be switched
- If some branch is merged into staging, deployment should take place only on Staging
- If Staging is then merged into QA, deployment should take place only on QA
- If some thing is merged into master, deployment should take place only on Production

I am using Bitbucket with AWS CodeDeploy service and repository is hosted on Bitbucket
Currently I am able to deploy the master branch on 1 instance. How can I achieve this?
My appspec.yml is as follows

```
image: php:7.2.13

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-common.sh
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-codedeploy.sh
    develop:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-common.sh
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
  custom:
    just-test-without-cache:
      - step:
          script:
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-common.sh
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code deploy script is pulling AWS variables from the environment, you can create a bash script to run before that step that sets the environment variables depending on the branch, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" = "master" ]
then
    export APPLICATION_NAME="..."
    export DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG="..."
    export DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME="Development"
    export S3_BUCKET=""..."
elif [ "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" = "staging" ]
then
    export APPLICATION_NAME="..."
    export DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG="..."
    export DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME="Staging"
    export S3_BUCKET=""..."
elif [ "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" = "production" ]
then
    export APPLICATION_NAME="..."
    export DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG="..."
    export DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME="Production"
    export S3_BUCKET=""..."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using [Deployments](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-deployments-940695276.html)

So you'd have something like:

```
image: php:7.2.13

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-common.sh
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-codedeploy.sh
    develop:
      - step:
          deployment: development
           caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - sh bitbucket-pipelines-common.sh
            - vendor/bin/phpunit
```